# Block chrome from accessing webcam on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, webcam

I don't want to open hangouts and automatically start broadcasting my webcam.

Ideally I would like to block it completely and allow it occasionally to hangouts.

So I found online some tutorial where it explained "how to do it" but it doesn't work.

I went to Settings -> Content Settings -> Media

[image: Google content media settings]

As you can see i cannot edit that, it only allows me to block or allow them at the same time, i cannot block only the webcam.

So, I'm starting to wonder if i could just "pull a switch" on my ubuntu through the terminal or something to enable/disable the webcam outside chrome?

Also tried going into the adobe flash settings and even after spending half an hour going through hundreds of websites inside a little box of 4 lines (how is this company so rich?) I can't even find google, besides if i did i still couldn't find the option to block only the webcam.

[image: Adobe flash privacy settings]

I use skype all the time to chat with friends and family and I use my webcam, its annoying to have to take out the tape and put it back 3 times/day.

So, is there anything I can do besides adding actual duck tape to my precious notebook webcam?

Edit: Yes, I added the ubuntu tag because one solution would be to disable the webcam completely on ubuntu (you can see i suggested it on the question) and enable it only when I'm going to use it, that way I don't have to use tape over my webcam, it looks gross, its time consuming and it's what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the perfect solution, loading/unloading the kernel module.

`sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo` to unload the webcam, `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` to load it back again.